# How to write SQL to check conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I need to write a SQL code that would do the following:

1. If there is only one record that has the status 'Pending', return that record and exit.
2. If there are multiple records with 'Pending' status, pick the record with the most recent 'Created_date'
3. If there are no 'Pending' records and only 'Active' records, pick the one with the most recent 'created_date'
4. If there are few 'Pending' and few 'Approved' records, Preference should be give to 'Pending' records with the most recent date

I tried CASE statements but its not working well. Please help.

Comment: You tagged your question with `mysql` **and** `sql-server` which one are you using?

Comment: How does (4) change anything? I'd have thought (2) already covers any such state.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Same for (1): (2) makes it redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged it both ways:

**Sql Server:**

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE Status IN ('Pending', 'Active')
ORDER BY Case WHEN Status='Pending' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, Created_Date DESC
```

**MySql:**

```
SELECT *
FROM `MyTable`
WHERE Status IN ('Pending', 'Active')
ORDER BY Case WHEN Status='Pending' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, Created_Date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

How I would do this if it would be my problem is:

pending_records =  "Select count(*) from records where status = 'pending'";

This would give me the number of pending records. According to this number I would solve all the other points with "if" statments.

```
if( pending_records == 1){
   Select the record and exit  
}else if ...
```

and continue with the other conditions.

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but I am thinking that if you do a descending order sort and take only the first record on EACH conditions and UNION them, you can then take the top record from that result. Something like this:

```
SELECT TOP(1) * 
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(1) * 
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Pending = 1
    ORDER BY Created_date DESC
    UNION
    SELECT TOP(1) * 
    FROM Table1 
    WHERE Approved = 1
    ORDER BY Created_date DESC
)
```

Note: This is for SQL Server though. For MySQL I think it's `LIMIT` instead of `TOP`